# I am attempting to publish a windows forms application using visual studio win files in the solution

Tags: publish, visual-studio-2022

I am attempting to publish an application from visual studio that has files in the solution. After instilling the program and executing it I get this error.
Could not find file
'C\Users[User Name]\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\7D4MADG.G94\9BLZYH2N.QOP\wdts..tion_0000000000000_0003.0000_8e564612a360b47a\wdAttrColSettings.xml

I need to know what I need to do to have the files in the Solution Items folder put in the wdts..tion_0000000000000_0003.0000_8e564612a360b47a folder when the application is installed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my brief experimentation in Visual Studio 2019, it doesn't look like you *can* copy Solution Items to the output directory.

This is, presumably, because there's no actual project (i.e. MSBuild or whatever) that would define those actions.

If you put those files inside one of the projects, you can use the "Copy to Output Directory" property.